# Un método codeigniter me funciona si le paso los valores directamente y si se los paso por variable me da error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo este código en un controlador de CI

```
$this->facturaModel->imprimir($inicio, $fin)
```

`$inicio` y `$fin` reciben los valores por `$_GET`

Si pongo `$this->facturaModel->imprimir($inicio, $fin)` me da `Error 500`

`$this->facturaModel->imprimir("1", "4")` me retorna el resultado esperado.

Valido el contenido mediante:

```
echo ("1" === $inicio) ? 'Ok' : 'Error';
echo ("4" === $fin) ? 'Ok' : 'Error';
```

En ambos casos me retorna el mensaje esperado, es decir "Ok".

¿Alguna idea de qué error puedo estar cometiendo y cómo solucionarlo?  Gracias!

Comment: Deberías incluir el error en tu pregunta.
¿El método donde se produce el error tiene tipos?
Prueba: `$this->facturaModel->imprimir((string) $inicio, (string) $fin)`
Y para tu validación de contenido, usa un triple igual: `===`.

Comment: Prueba la comparación con `('1' === $inicio)` y `('4' === $fin)`.

Comment: Orici y @Sal gracias por sus respuestas. Me fueron de utilidad. El error se debía a una instancia externa a la función.

Comment: **Problema solucionado.**